# Installing ethernet drivers with no install package

Tags: windows-7, drivers, ethernet, transfer

I recently got my new Sony Vaio laptop and formatted it into Windows 7 Ultimate. I would like to use the Windows Easy Transfer Tool over a network connection to transfer some of my files over from my desktop PC.

Before I do this though, I need to install the ethernet LAN drivers (I'm currently using the built in Wifi).

I downloaded the original LAN driver that came with my Vaio originally from the Sony website:

http://support.vaio.sony.eu/computing/vaio/downloads/preinstalled/index.aspx?l=en_GB&m=VPCEB1Z0E_B

[Scroll down to the 450KB Ethernet driver]

When I unzip the package, these files are inside:

```
yk62x64.cat
yk62x64.dll
yk62x64.inf
yk62x64.sys
```

As you can see, no installer. Can anyone guide me through how to properly install these drivers? I have thought of using Google but I'm clueless as to what query to use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzip them to a directory. Remember which directory.

Right click "My Computer" or "Computer" or whatever you've renamed it.

Go To Properties.

Go to Hardware.

Go to Device Manager.

Go to "Network Adapters"

Right click on your device.

Go to the "Driver" tab.

Click on "Update Driver..."

Click through the first window of the wizard, and then choose "Install from a Specific Location."

Pick the directory where you unzipped the driver files. It should install them and tell you to reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my Ethernet device didn't apear under "Network Adapters", but instead under "Other devices" called "Ethernet Controller". I'm guessing that's the one so I'll try installing the drivers to that. Thanks again :) EDIT: Yeah, after I installed the drivers the device is listed under Network adapters. All is good! :D